# Help with printing table data

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, expression-construction

I am looking for the way of building a Table in a fast way. My true table evaluates huge functions with a system of differential equations . Let us for simplicity consider this:

```
Z = 0.9;
Table[-3 x^2 + y Z, {x, 0.1, 3, 0.5}, {y, 0.1, 5, 0.5}]

{{0.06, 0.51, 0.96, 1.41, 1.86, 2.31, 2.76, 3.21, 3.66, 
  4.11}, {-0.99, -0.54, -0.09, 0.36, 0.81, 1.26, 1.71, 2.16, 2.61, 
  3.06}, {-3.54, -3.09, -2.64, -2.19, -1.74, -1.29, -0.84, -0.39, 
  0.06, 0.51}, {-7.59, -7.14, -6.69, -6.24, -5.79, -5.34, -4.89, \
-4.44, -3.99, -3.54}, {-13.14, -12.69, -12.24, -11.79, -11.34, \
-10.89, -10.44, -9.99, -9.54, -9.09}, {-20.19, -19.74, -19.29, \
-18.84, -18.39, -17.94, -17.49, -17.04, -16.59, -16.14}}
```

I want to print only the values from `[0 to 3.06]`
My question: is there a way to instruct Table to stop evaluating as soon as the conditions are fulfilled? This might considerably shorten its evaluation time.

I was thinking of using `Reap/Sow`. Here is my tried:

```
Reap[Do[If[-3 x^2 + y Z, Sow[-3 x^2 + y Z], Break[]], {x, 0.1, 3, 
   0.5}, {y, 0.1, 5, 0.5}]]
```

Help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will stop at the first value that is not in $[0,3.06]$:

```
Z = 0.9;
Reap[Do[If[u = -3 x^2 + y Z; 0 <= u <= 3.06, Sow[u], Break[]],
        {x, 0.1, 3, 0.5}, {y, 0.1, 5, 0.5}]][[2, 1]]

(*    {0.06, 0.51, 0.96, 1.41, 1.86, 2.31, 2.76}    *)
```

This will generate all values that are in $[0,3.06]$:

```
Z = 0.9;
Reap[Do[If[u = -3 x^2 + y Z; 0 <= u <= 3.06, Sow[u]],
        {x, 0.1, 3, 0.5}, {y, 0.1, 5, 0.5}]][[2, 1]]

(*    {0.06, 0.51, 0.96, 1.41, 1.86, 2.31, 2.76, 0.36,
       0.81, 1.26, 1.71, 2.16, 2.61, 3.06, 0.06, 0.51}    *)
```

You could also generate $(x,y,u)$ tuples:

```
Z = 0.9;
Reap[Do[If[u = -3 x^2 + y Z; 0 <= u <= 3.06, Sow[{x, y, u}]],
        {x, 0.1, 3, 0.5}, {y, 0.1, 5, 0.5}]][[2, 1]]

(*    {{0.1, 0.1, 0.06}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.51}, {0.1, 1.1, 0.96},
       {0.1, 1.6, 1.41}, {0.1, 2.1, 1.86}, {0.1, 2.6, 2.31},
       {0.1, 3.1, 2.76}, {0.6, 1.6, 0.36}, {0.6, 2.1, 0.81},
       {0.6, 2.6, 1.26}, {0.6, 3.1, 1.71}, {0.6, 3.6, 2.16},
       {0.6, 4.1, 2.61}, {0.6, 4.6, 3.06}, {1.1, 4.1, 0.06},
       {1.1, 4.6, 0.51}}    *)
```

Comment: What does `[2,1] `means ?

Comment: @aluuzz From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html): `Reap[expr]` gives the value of `expr` together with all expressions to which `Sow` has been applied during its evaluation. Expressions sown using `Sow[e]` or `Sow[e,Subscript[tag, i]]` with different tags are given in different lists.

Comment: Does `Do` short circuit evaluation, or will carry out each iteration no matter what?

Comment: @aluuzz Please start reading the documentation and doing your own experiments.

Comment: I will thanks! Last things: How to apply `While` iteration instead of `Do` if could help me with that I  I really appreciate it. `Reap[While[-3 x^2 + y Z 0 <= && <= 3, Sow[-3 x^2 + y Z]; {x, 2.3, 3.1, 0.01}, {y, 2.3, 3.1, 0.01}]][[2, 
  1]]`

Comment: @aluuzz `While` doesn't work that way.

Comment: Do you know how?if so would you help me with that?

Comment: @aluuzz The given combination of `Do` and `Break` does precisely what you want. No need to force `While` into this pattern.

Comment: Thanks so much @ Roman!